# What exactly is the relationship of Hunter Zolomon to Jay Garrick?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In a recent episode, it was revealed that:

> Zoom was actually Hunter Zolomon, a serial killer who, according to Harrison Wells, was easily recognizable to everyone on their world.

And yet,

> Jay Garrick is also a well know figure on their world, as Earth-2's Flash.

So...why do they, as far as I can tell, look exactly alike?

> On the first ocassion of Hunter Zolomon dressing up like the Flash, why didn't everyone identify him as Hunter Zolomon?

Have I missed something here?

Comment: Wells didn't make the connection until Zolomon's name was mentioned. Look at the picture of Zolomon that they show. He's fully bearded and crazy looking. He looks nothing like the clean-cut Jay Garrick.

Comment: And Eobard Thawne looked nothing like Dr. Wells.

Comment: Is it as simple as that? That Zolomon shaved his beard off and no one made the connection?

Comment: is it as simple as that? that superman puts a pair of glasses on and no one made the connection?

Comment: @phantom42: many people find difficult to admit that no one in-universe made the immediate connection between Superman and Clark Kent. And in the Jay/Hunter Zolomon situation, it is even worse: both are very famous in their universe, whereas in many versions, Clark Kent is a talented but relatively unknown journalist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we now know from the final episode,

> Jay Garrick is Earth-3 Flash, and Zoom has abducted him and taken his name to pose as Flash in Earth-2

Answer (score -2):

At this point of the show diffusion, we clearly don't know everything and thus cannot answer this yet. Greg Berlanti has stated on Twitter that there is other things to come. (see https://twitter.com/GBerlanti/status/722882921854427138)

If you allow fanmade theories ; my first one is that Zoom is actually Hunter Solomon, and he is actually Earth 1 native. Jay is still E2 flash who just happen to look alike.

(My second theory is not really nice, and is about writters throwing away logic and the first half of the season out of the window, just to play poor twists. Because CW.)

Comment: Welcome to SFF. While "We Don't Know" can be an acceptable answer please back this claim up. Try linking that Tweet you mentioned. This is not a place for speculation, if you are suggesting a theory it must be backed up from the source material.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's where we're at. What baffles me about this, though, is that Harrison Wells should have id'd Zolomon on sight, rather than accepting him as Jay Garrick. WTH?

Comment: And if Zoom is Earth One's Hunter, then who is the guy that "Jay" points to in the park?

Comment: Maybe it's own past self ? Well, I have nothing to back my theorie, but I have found this tweet and linking it.